# Flutter - how to change selected text color?

Tags: dart, flutter

[image]

i have this `TextFormField` so far, i've changed the highlighted background color with `textSelectionColor` property and the handlebars color with `textSelectionHandleColor`. But how can i change the text color of the highlighted text as shown in the image above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't find any property that directly does this but i found an alternative way `withOpacity()` function, which does the job as intended. Example:

```
Color(0xff00BCD4).withOpacity(0.3)
```